# Custom servlet response

Tags: java, servlets

In mapping method (Spring controller) I have `HttpServletResponse` and I have full response data. This data could be written to the socket directly. It already contains all `status/headers/body` so it is complete HTTP response. What would be the right way to return this response to the client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You'll have to parse it, extract the status line, headers, and body and use the appropriate methods to set them in the `HttpServletResponse`.